# how can i set checkbox value in header template in gridview? inc# side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I want to change the checkbox value with reader values in grid view in cs code not in asp.net side? How can i set the it?
"headerCell.FindControl("c") as CheckBox = true" it does not work

I tried it

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        foreach (TableCell headerCell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            if (reader["isSelected"].ToString().Equals("true"))
            {
                headerCell.FindControl("c") as CheckBox = true;
            }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kindly Add more content in your question

Comment: "I tried it" Nice try, what happened?

Comment: headerCell.FindControl("c") as CheckBox = true it does not work

Comment: So you want to check every checkbox in the gridview-header if `reader["isSelected"]` is true?

Comment: yes, but I cannot change the value of checbkox in gridview

Comment: that line will return object, try to set the Checked property to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find your `CheckBox` in the header in this way:

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("c"); // change that ID to something more meaningful
```

You can check/uncheck it in this way:

```
if(reader.Read())
    chk.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("isSelected"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CheckBox ChkBoxRows = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("c") as CheckBox;
```

Then you can set `true` or `false` property to **ChkBoxRows** which reflects to **c**

```
if(reader.Read())
   ChkBoxRows.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("isSelected"));
```